# Are there any cases where a private boolean (primitive) field variable defaults to something other than false?

Tags: java, spring, boolean, default-value

Say I have a class, `DisplaySpecificType.java` which extends the abstract class `DisplayBase.java`. In my class I have a few fields:

```
private boolean noData;
private List<String> selections;
private List<Integer> intSelections;
```

And in the overridden method, the first thing I do is retrieve some data:

```
@Override
protected void initResponse(DataHolder holder) {
    String dataString = holder.getDataString();
    intSelections = prepareSelections(dataString);
    ...
}
```

Here's the prepare method:

```
protected List<Integer> prepareSelections(String dataString) {

    String trimmedData = StringUtils.trimToNull(dataString); // Empty strings -> null
    selections = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (trimmedData == null) {
        noData = true;
    } else {

    // Do some operations on trimmedData, convert to integers 
    // (in String format) and add to selections array

    }

    intSelections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (!noData) {
        for (String index : selections) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(index) - 1;
            intSelections.add(num);
        }
    }
    return intSelections;
}
```

I can't really run the application from Eclipse as it interacts with several others, but I have several unit tests (Junit) that test the functionality. Creating a `DataHolder` object and setting the `dataString` in the test causes no issues and everything comes out dandy.

In practice, however, running the application that invokes this class caused `intSelections` to turn up empty, even when `dataString` was not. I logged the value of `selections` right after it was populated with the data from `trimmedValues` (outside of the if/else statement), which was being filled with the correct data when it should have been. I then logged the value of `intSelections` right after the for loop that populated it, and to my surprise, it was empty.

So I'd have something like this:

> logger: selections = [1,2,3]
>
> logger: intSelections = []

The `noData` boolean can't be set to `true` if `selections` has data. But clearly the if statement that populates `intSelections` is being passed over, leading me to think that `noData` has somehow been set to `true`.

Initializing `noData` to `false` at the beginning of the prepare method fixed the problem, but I'm still stumped as to why.

We're using spring, maven, and MOM queues, but I'm not terribly familiar with how it all executes. I do know that no properties are being set in the spring configs, it just initializes the `DisplaySpecificType` class via spring bean in the service context.

Sorry for the long-winded question, does anyone know what's going on here?

EDIT:

As I mentioned in the comments, here's what I think happened:

I was assuming that every command issued to the main application (commands go in and are eventually parsed by my project, which is where DataHolder and dataString come from) would create a new instance of this class, but this might not be the case.

If input was passed that caused dataString to be null or empty, noData would be set to true, and if the instance was not destroyed it would remain true when the next input was passed through. It's not very clear to me how the application interacts with all the other programs, so this is just my best guess.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand the question. `if (trimmedData == null)` you set the `noData` to true, it didn't initialize to `true`. dataString must be empty or null.

Comment: A `boolean` instance field will always be initialized to `false` by default. There must be something modifying it.

Comment: I was assuming that every command issued to the main application (commands go in and are parsed in my project, which is where `DataHolder` and `dataString come from) would create a new instance of this class, but I may be wrong in this assumption.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If input was passed that caused `dataString` to be null or empty, `noData` would be set to true, and if the instance was not destroyed it would remain true when the next input was passed through. It's a huge web of interconnected programs, it's a little difficult to understand. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any cases where a private boolean (primitive) field variable
>   defaults to something other than false?

No.  As others have mentioned, something else must be going on with your code.  Per the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables
>
> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is
>   used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):
>
> ...
>
> - For type boolean, the default value is false.